# No matching operands [template] / cannot convert from Type const* to Type

Tags: c++, templates

Let me post my code first:

Set.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

 template<class _type> class Set
 {
 public:
    Set();
    Set m_add(Set _set1, Set _set2);
    void m_addElem(Set *const _set, _type _elem); 
    void m_deleteElem(Set *const _set, _type _elem); 
    void m_addArray(_type _arr[], int _size); 
    Set(Set &_coll);
    void operator+(_type _num);
    void operator+(_type _elem[]);
    Set operator+(Set *const _set);
    void operator-(_type _num);
    Set & operator=(Set &_set);
    void m_display();
    int m_check(_type elem);
    ~Set(void);
private:
    _type * m_pelements;
    int m_setSize;
};
```

Set.cpp

```
    #pragma warning( disable : 4996 )
#include "Set.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



template <class _type>
Set<_type>::Set()
{
    m_setSize = 0;
}

template <class _type>
Set<_type>::Set(Set<_type> &_coll)
{
        m_setSize = _coll.m_setSize;
        m_pelements = new _type[_coll.m_setSize];
        for (int i = 0;i<m_setSize;i++)
        {
            m_pelements[i] = _coll.m_pelements[i];
        }

}

template <class _type>
Set<_type>::~Set()
{
    delete [] m_pelements;
}

template <class _type>
Set<_type> Set<_type>::m_add(Set<_type> _set1, Set<_type> _set2)
{
     Set<_type> finalSet;
    finalSet = _set1;
    for (int i = 0;i<_set2->m_setSize;i++)
    {
        m_addElem(finalSet, _set2->m_pelements[i]);
    }
    return finalSet;
}

template <class _type>
void Set<_type>::m_addElem(Set<_type> *const _set, _type _elem)
{

 if (_set->m_setSize == 0)
 {
_set->m_pelements = new _type[1];
    _set->m_pelements[0] = _elem;
    _set->m_setSize += 1;
}
else 
{
    _set->m_setSize += 1;
    _type * helpElements = new _type[_set->m_setSize];
    std::copy(_set->m_pelements, _set->m_pelements + _set->m_setSize-1,  helpElements);
    helpElements[_set->m_setSize-1] = _elem;
    delete [] _set->m_pelements;
    _set->m_pelements = helpElements;
    /*
    _type * helpElements = new _type[_set->m_setSize];
    for (int i = 0;i<_set->m_setSize;i++)
    {
        helpElements[i] =  _set->m_pelements[i];
    }
    delete _set->m_pelements;
    _set->m_setSize += 1;
    _set->m_pelements = new _type[_set->m_setSize];
    for (int i = 0;i<_set->m_setSize;i++)
    {
        _set->m_pelements[i] =  helpElements[i];
    }
    _set->m_pelements[_set->m_setSize-1] = _elem;
    */
}

}

template <class _type>
void Set<_type>::m_deleteElem(Set<_type> *const _set, _type _elem)
{
    int index = _set->m_check(_elem);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        int k = 0;
        _set->m_setSize -= 1;
        _type * temp = new _type[_set->m_setSize];
        for (int i = 0;i<_set->m_setSize;i++)
      {
         if (i == index)
            k++;
        temp[i] = _set->m_pelements[i+k];
    }
    delete [] _set->m_pelements;
    _set->m_pelements = temp;
    }
}

template <class _type>
void Set<_type>::m_addArray(_type _elem[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
    m_addElem(this,_elem[i]);
 }
}

template <class _type>
void Set<_type>::operator+( _type _elem)
{
    m_addElem(this,_elem);  
}

template <class _type>
Set<_type> Set<_type>::operator+(Set<_type> *const _set)
{
    return m_add(this,_set);    
}

template <class _type>
void Set<_type>::operator+( _type _elem[])
{
    m_addArray(this,_elem); 
}

template <class _type>
void Set<_type>::operator-( _type _elem)
{
    m_deleteElem(this,_elem);   
}

template <class _type>
Set<_type> & Set<_type>::operator=(Set<_type> &_set)
{
    if(&_set==this) return *this;

    delete [] m_pelements;

    m_setSize = _coll.m_setSize;
    m_pelements = new _type[_coll.m_setSize];
    for (int i = 0;i<m_setSize;i++)
    {
        m_pelements[i] = _coll.m_pelements[i];
    }

}

template <class _type>
void Set<_type>::m_display()
{
        for (int i = 0;i<m_setSize;i++)
        {
        std::cout << m_pelements[i] << "   " ;
        }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <class _type>
int Set<_type>::m_check(_type _elem)
{
    for (int i = 0;i<m_setSize;i++)
    {
    if (m_pelements[i] == _elem)
         return i;
  }
return -1;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4996 )
#include "Set.h"
#include "Set.cpp"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    Set<std::string> zbior1;
    zbior1 + std::string("abc");
    zbior1 + std::string("abcd");
    zbior1 + std::string("abcdef");
    zbior1 + std::string("XD");
    zbior1.m_display();
    zbior1 - "XD";
    zbior1.m_display();

    std::string tablica[3] = {"ala", "ma", "kota" };
    zbior1.m_addArray(tablica,3);
    zbior1.m_display();

    Set<std::string> zbior2;
    zbior2 + std::string("abDDc");
    zbior2 + std::string("abcdDD");
    zbior2 + std::string("abcdeDDf");
    zbior2 + std::string("XDDD");
    zbior2.m_display();

    Set<std::string> zbior3;
    zbior3 = zbior1 + zbior2; //HERE'S THE PROBLEM
}
```

Problem appears int the last line of Main.cpp 
When arguments of `Set operator+` are `(Set *const _set)` I get error " no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Set<_type>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)'" and if i remove `*const` there's different error saying "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Set<_type> *const ' to 'Set<_type>'"

I have no idea how to repair it.

Comment: [OT]: `#include "Set.cpp"`... Rename Set.cpp into "Set.inl" or "Set.hxx"

Comment: I believe it is correct but Can you tell me somehting more about it?

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
Set operator+(Set *const _set);
```

is defined as taking a `const` pointer (which is for sure what you don't want), but you then pass to it an object instead, and not the address of an object. Pass by reference, like

```
Set operator+(Set const & _set);
```

Try reading [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) for a very good introduction to the subject.

Answer (score 0):

This method:

```
Set operator+(Set *const _set);
```

should probably look like:

```
Set operator+(Set const &rhs) const;
```

if it's going to stay a method. See the link in vsoftco's answer for why it should probably be a free non-friend function instead, implemented in terms of `operator+=`.

You pasted the same message for both errors, afaics, but at least one is complaining about the attempt to pass `zbior2` to a method expecting a pointer.

Comment: The second one is odd, but it should work correctly with the syntax in my asnswer. The canonical forms of operator overloads are well-documented, not least in that link.

Comment: It is not working. Right now I'm reading vsoftco's link and I will try to find a soultion.

Comment: The definition of `operator+` in your .cpp file doesn't match the declaration at all, so this code must be wrong anyway. You might just have to try again with a minimal complete example.